# How many days do I need to visit Magic Kingdom at Disney World, Orlando?

Tags: disney

I have a 4-year-old kid. So far I was learning about Disney World, there are attractions we will not be able to visit because of her age.

Considering that, how many days will we need to visit Magic Kingdom at Orlando?  I read on a webpage we will need three days only for Magic Kingdom, and two will be enough to know more than a half. Other webpage says one day is enough for Magic Kingdom and for each Disney park.

Do you have any personal experience? One day is very little? Three days is too much?

Comment: As long as you take your toddler to the Hoop do Doo Revue, 1 1/2 days will be totally sufficient. Honestly.   BUT your question is an opinion poll and this site doesn't work for those. Unfortunately, placing this question in the review queue as 'opinion-based'.  Sorry...

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As elsewhere on StackExchange, it is best to demonstrate your own research. There are numerous blogs and guides available on the Internet that suggest itineraries for a [single day](http://www.disneytouristblog.com/1-day-magic-kingdom-plans/), or [three days](https://www.yahoo.com/style/insiders-guide-to-walt-disney-world-the-perfect-3-day-92866790987.html), and so on, and you should consult those first.

Comment: Also as elsewhere on StackExchange, asking for personal experiences or opinions is frowned upon. We want questions that can be answered in a definitive way, supported with objective references. I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: @GayotFow Hi! I understand that this question could be considered an opinion poll, but to be honest, I don't found a different way to ask for something which could be considered pretty fair.

Comment: @choster Yeah, I understand. But, yes, I did my homework as you can see at the question. Because the different advices I found, I decided to ask here :-)

Comment: @choster Thank you for the links!  I didn't find that blog.

Comment: It's not opining based. Disney has made visiting Walt Disney World a science experiment.  I'm happy to answer any more questions you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:) Magic Kingdom is my park.

If you go on a light crowd day, one day at Magic Kingdom may be enough.  Here is a site that lists anticipated crowds: [Orlando Crowd Calendar](https://www.undercovertourist.com/orlando/crowd-calendar/)

Keep in mind, a 4yr old will start the day very enthusiastic but will eventually fall asleep :)

Also, FastPass planning is very important to fully experiencing MK.  The sooner you buy passes or make hotel reservations (at a Disney hotel) to sooner you can make get FastPasses.  If you do stay at a Disney Hotel, you definitely want to take advantage of the Extra Magic Hours benefit.

How long you want to dedicate to the Magic Kingdom depends on how long you will have at Walt Disney World.  If you have 3 days, I would recommend 1) Magic Kingdom, 2) Disney's Animal Kingdom, 3) Disney's Hollywood Studios* and/or Magic Kingdom.

*Disney's Hollywood Studios is undergoing major construction right now so you won't necessarily need a full day.

Finally, EPCOT is not a 4yr old's park, with one possibly **HUGE** exception: Frozen Ever After.

+1 for The Hoop-Dee-Doo Musical Revue.  We go every year.